# How to get the executed javascript file directory?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a javascript file in a directory like:

```
/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/themeName/users/js
```

And there are some PHP files I want to make Ajax Requests to in this directory:

```
/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/themeName/users
```

How to get the PHP files directory in Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: your ajax call will specify the php file path, other than that I'm not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a file referenced (say, in `<head>`) on your page

```
<head>
    <script src="~/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/themeName/users/js/test-file.js"></script>
</head>
```

you can pass the file name (without the `.js` extension) into this function, together with it's folder name, and it should return the path with the folder name removed:

```
$(function () {
    var getFilePath = function (fileName, scriptFolderName) {
        var reg = new RegExp("" + fileName + ".*\\.js");
        var regReplace = new RegExp("/" + scriptFolderName + "/" + fileName + ".*\\.js.*$");
        // Find the file in the page
        var fileSrc = $("script[src]").filter(function () {
            return reg.test($(this).attr("src"));
        }).first();

        if (0 === fileSrc.length) {
            console.log("Could not get location of " + fileName + ".js");
        } else {
            // Return the path without parent folder
            return fileSrc.attr("src").replace(regReplace, "/");
        }
    };
    // Call the function with the referenced filename and folder
    // (the function could be adjusted to remove the need for the 
    // folder name, by hardcoding it, but this is more flexible)
    var filePath = getFilePath("test-file", "js");
    console.log("filePath: : " + filePath);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , Please update your answer change `filename` in this line ` console.log("Could not get location of " + filename + ".js");` with `fileName`